# Is there a way to convert datetime to acceptable format?

Tags: python, datetime, optimization, format

I have a program that predicts stock market with ETNA (Tinkoff's repository)

```
train_ts, test_ts = ts.train_test_split(train_start='2021-05-30',
                                    train_end='2022-04-30',
                                    test_start='2022-05-08',
                                    test_end='2022-05-30')
```

I am trying to actualise programm for each day by using
'today = datetime.today()'
but when i have an error

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [today] of type str

how to convert "today" to an acceptable format?
Maybe you can suggest better ways to do what i want. As i undersatnd i can't use today with strptime

Comment: Could you add details, which line of code exactly throws the error (i.e. copy the error traceback)? IIUC, the `train_test_split` method [does accept strings or pandas.Timestamps](https://github.com/tinkoff-ai/etna/blob/cb28c3aa2eeaa28ddc465afdbc9bc8541697a707/etna/datasets/tsdataset.py#L24), so I can't see how your example throws that error.

Comment: raise self._invalid_indexer("slice", label) from err

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [today] of type str

Is that what you asking for? Thank you for answering! @FObersteiner

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert a datetime object to a formatted string.

This particular function will convert a datetime object into a string matching the format specified in your example (and the ETNA docs).

```py
dt_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i have another problem! TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [today] of type str